# Minimum and maximum values for CSS background-position property

Tags: css

What are the maximum and minimum values, in pixels, for the CSS `background-position` property?

More precisely, if we use

```
background-position: xpos ypos;
```

where `xpos` and `ypos` are pixels, what is the allowed range for `xpos` and `ypos`?

Comment: My guess is that it's browser-specific... If you give a bit more background into what you're trying to accomplish maybe I could be a bit more helpful

Comment: If iOS is important, there are [resource limits](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006482-SW15) that will probably restrict the maximum *image size* you can use.

Comment: @Number1SuperGuy: yeah, this is the safest bet and I could figure out myself. In fact, I was (implicitly) asking if there is some standard  (or de facto) limit and if anybody knows what is the limit empowered by, let's say, Chrome, Firefox and IE. A bit more flexibility could be a bit more helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values for [`background-position`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html#propdef-background-position) when specified with pixels as unit is defined as `<length>`, which is a real number.

The [specification for a real number](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#numbers) doesn't mention any limit for the number itself.

The actual values that are usable would be limited by the implementation in the browser. There is a limit to the size of the document based on the size of the variables that are used to keep track of it. Older browsers could have a limit like 32767 pixels (16 bits, signed), but nowadays we see larger web pages, and the limit is likely to be more something like 2147483647 pixels (32 bits, signed).

As browsers are implemented differently, you should keep the values to a reasonable range just to be safe.

Comment: I see. However, I wasn't able to find out the limits for any browser... It feels like this feature is undocumented.